# How to compare 2 strings by its hashes

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash, computer-science

If i have 2 strings (1 needle and 1 haystack) and i want to compare all substrings(same needle length) hashes in haystack with hash of needle string.

example:

```
na      << needle   , pHashes: 0 14 45 0 0 0 0 0 0  , needle hash = 45
banana  << haystack , pHashes: 0 2 33 13487 43278 12972572 41601723 0 0 
-----------------------------
^^      << 1st substring (ba)
 ^^     << 2nd substring (an)
  ^^    << 3rd substring (na)
   ^^   << 4th substring (an)
    ^^  << 5th substring (na)
```

i want to compute all prefix hashes of haystack string and calculate hash value of indices i and j to get the hash of the substring s[i…j].  ex.  check if hash(needle) == hash(3rd substring)

i use function `getHash` to get string hash:

```
const long long hashMod = (long long) ( 1e15 + 9 );
const int prime = 31;

long long getHash(string str) {
    const int len = str.length();
    ll hash = 0, powVal = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        hash = ( hash + ( str[i] - 'a' + 1 ) * powVal ) % hashMod;
        ( powVal *= prime ) %= hashMod;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

and function `get(l , r)` to get hash of range [ l ... r]:

```
long long get(int l, int r) {
    const int len = haystack.length();
    return ( ( pHashes[r] - pHashes[l-1] ) * powers[len - r]) % hashMod;
}
```

`powers[] = 1 31 961 29791 923521 28629151`

my main problem with move all substrings to the same power.

Comment: Are you trying to implement Rabin–Karp?

Comment: Because strlen takes linear time over a string and won't work if your string has an internal null characters. While std::string has a size_t member dedicated to the length.